# Converting YUV_420_888 To Base64 Android corrupted image

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, android-camera, yuv

I am currently working on a project which uses OpenCV in background mode to detect faces while the app is playing videos .
I've managed to run OpenCV as a service and I am using an ImageReader instance to capture the images

```
    private ImageReader mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1);
```

What I am trying to do is to get the detected face image and send it to the backend side , the image from the Imagereader is converted to Mat so I have both access to the Mat type and the Image type.
I've managed to convert the aquired image to Yuv image then to jpg ( byte array ) by using both toYuvImage and toJpegImage methods from this link : https://blog.minhazav.dev/how-to-convert-yuv-420-sp-android.media.Image-to-Bitmap-or-jpeg/#how-to-convert-yuv_420_888-image-to-jpeg-format

After converting the image to an array of bytes , I'm also trying to convert it to base64 to send it using http , the problem is when I try to put the imageQuality to 100 in toJpegImage , the result of the base64 image is looking corrupted , but when I put the value to something lower like 15 or 10 the image output ( resolution ) is better but the quality is bad , I am not sure if this problem is related to the resolution

```
  byte[] jpegDataTest = ImageUtil.toJpegImage(detectionImage,15);
           String base64New = Base64.encodeToString(jpegDataTest, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

PS : I am converting the image each time a face is detected in a for loop

```
        for(Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()){}
```

compress quality is set to 100 : https://i.postimg.cc/YqSmFxrT/quality100.jpg

compress quality is set to 15
[image: 15 quality]

```
public static byte[] toJpegImage(Image image, int imageQuality) {
    if (image.getFormat() != ImageFormat.YUV_420_888) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid image format");
    }

    YuvImage yuvImage = toYuvImage(image);
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    // Convert to jpeg
    byte[] jpegImage = null;
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), imageQuality, out);
        jpegImage = out.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   return jpegImage;
}

 private static byte[] YUV_420_888toNV21(Image image) {
    byte[] nv21;
    ByteBuffer yBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer vuBuffer = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();

    int ySize = yBuffer.remaining();
    int vuSize = vuBuffer.remaining();

    nv21 = new byte[ySize + vuSize];

    yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize);
    vuBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vuSize);



    return nv21;
}
```

Comment: sounds like something is length-limited, and your picture gets to be larger than acceptable. something around 64 KB?

Comment: when I try to convert the image from base64 to jpg online here are the details
• Resolution: 352×288 • MIME type: image/jpeg • Extension: jpg,• Size: 2.92 KB • Download: image.jpg • Channels: 3 • Bit depth:

Comment: all this base64 stuff is never a good idea, honestly. everything out there is binary-safe, if you know how to use it. that includes HTTP POST requests. what isn't binary-safe is various "text" handling stuff that might introduce or convert line breaks randomly. why do you think you need base64?

Comment: I thought base64 would be the fastest way to send these detection images to the backend without interrupting the other going stuff ( video player , detection ...) and I don't need to store these images for now so I went for base64 , but if you believe there's better way to send this images with that format using http post requests , please let me know , thanks!

Comment: just stuff the binary data in a POST request. you're gonna POST this anyway, right?

Comment: Yes i'm gonna POST it , but what I don't understand is the type of the image is Image YUV_420_888 ,  how can I convert it later on in the backend ( python )

Comment: the `YUV_420_888toNV21` gives you bytes (without a header that would contain width/height). the `toJpegImage` claims to make a real JPEG file. both return `byte[]` so that's good. those byte[] you can treat like a file upload. the POST request will look the same.